# How to create a more accurate calculation of months with Google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I'm using this formula `=DATEDIF(B2; C2; "M")` on Googles spreadsheet to calculate months.

I expected when entering a begindate `B2` **22-4-2013** and enddate `C2` **31-8-2014** to get an exact result: **16,3397**.

Unexpected result is only full months **16**.

Comment: Welcome. How did you come up with `16,3397`?

Comment: I used an other calculation program for this

Comment: *"I used an other calculation program for this"*. Like...? Please be specific. If it is an online one, do share the URL.

Comment: Ah according to the program  there are `30,41671512` days in a month and `497` days in this period. Therefore period in `days/days a month` = `497/30,41671512` = 16,3397 months

Comment: =(C2-B2)/(365/12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for

> *"a more accurate calculation of months with google spreadsheets?"*.

Also in my question on how you came up with the number `16,3397` you said

> according to the program there are 30,41671512 days in a month and 497 days in this period

So this is the formula you should be using

```
=DAYS(C2+1,B2)/(365/12)
```

You can also use

```
=DATEDIF(B2,C2+1,"D")/(365/12)
```

We use `C2+1` to also count the last day as well.
The way Google counts, it does not take in account the last day.

[image]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments above, it sounds like you've already solved your own problem but just haven't realized it:

`=(DATEDIF(B2; C2; "D")+1)/30,41671512`

To be ultra-clear, use "D" instead of "M", add 1 (since it appears you are counting the number of days between any two consecutive dates as 2 not the true difference of 1), and divide by the days-per-month figure you provided.